# MySQL server has gone away issue

Tags: python, mysql

I am newbie in python, so, it looks like my first project on that lang.
Everytime when I'm trying to run my script - I get different answers from mysql server.
The most frequent answer is `OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`
Sometimes I get output `Thread: 11 commited` (see code below).
And sometimes `emergency stop` (traslated, I have russian output in console).
Whatever if output full of `commited` - records in table still the same.

```
import MySQLdb
import pyping
import socket, struct
from threading import Thread

def ip2int(addr):
    """Convert ip to integer"""
    return struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(addr))[0]

def int2ip(addr):
    """Convert integer to ip"""
    return socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("!I", addr))

def ping(ip):
    """Pinging client"""
    request = pyping.ping(ip, timeout=100, count=1)
    return int(request.max_rtt)

class UpdateThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, records, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.database = MySQLdb.connect(host="***", port=3306, user="root", passwd="***", db="dns")
        self.cursor = database.cursor()
        self.name = name
        self.records = records
    def run(self):
        print(self.name)
        for r in self.records:
            #latency = ping(int2ip(r[1])) what the hell :x
            #ip = str(int2ip(r[1]))
            id = str(r[0])
            self.cursor.execute("""update clients set has_subn=%s where id=%s""" % (id, id))
        self.database.commit()
        print(self.name + " commited")

#start
database = MySQLdb.connect(host="***", port=3306, user="root", passwd="***", db="dns")
cursor = database.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select * from clients""")
data = cursor.fetchall() #All records from DataBase
count = len(data) 
threads_counter = 10 #We are creating 10 threads for all records
th_count = count / threads_counter #Count of records for each thread
last_thread = count % threads_counter #Last records
threads = []

i = 0
while i < (count - last_thread):
    temp_list = data[i:(i+th_count)]
    #print(temp_list)
    threads.append(UpdateThread(records = temp_list, name = "Thread: " + str((i/3) + 1)).start())
    i += th_count

threads.append(UpdateThread(records = data[i: count], name = "Thread: 11").start())
```

P.S.
Another answers I found here is not helping me.

UPD:
I found that some(everytime another) thread print
`OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')` and all next threads print `OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')`

Comment: "MySQL server has gone away" means that your database connection has timed out because you opened it, then started doing something else time-consuming and didn't interact with the database until that other thing finished.

Comment: @Hammerite But script is opening connection and every new thread doing it too. Why is it?

Comment: Does it work if you open just one connection (i.e. only one thread)? If so, what's the minimum number of threads for which you see the problem?

Comment: @Hammerite if I try to do it without any thread - it works in one loop for all records. Now there 32 records, but will be 500000+ after turning it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your DB connections when you're done with them or else the DB server will become overwhelmed and make your connections expire. For your program, I would change your code so that you have only one DB connection. You can pass a reference to it to your UpdateThread instances and close it when you're done.

```
database.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Result is the same. It works only with one thread.